# MySql result in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I know that this question have been asked more times than amen in church. But i am gonna ask anyway.

I am going to an boardgame convention in Denmark and i figured "Hey we could use a locate a players SMS service"
So i build it. BUT when i have to take some data out of one Database like the phonenumber and the name. And i need to insert that into another Database (where my SMS injection looks) But a variable can only store 1 number and i need to store 10 ~ 50 numbers and Names
Here is what i got so far.

```
    // escape variables for security
    $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name']);
    $Players = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Players']);
    $Game = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Game']);

    $besked = "Du har oprettet et spil med navn $Name og er et $Game som mangler $Players spiller(e).";
    echo $besked;
    echo "<br>";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM brugere where $Game = 'Ja'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['Navn'] . " " . $row['VCNummer'];
      echo "<br>";
    $PhoneNumber = $row['Phonenumber'];  

    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="smssend.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="besked" value="<?php echo "$besked"; ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="PhoneNumber" value="<?php echo "$PhoneNumber"; ?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send data">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And when i am trying to put it in the other Database

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASSWORD","SMSDATABASE");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // escape variables for security

    $besked = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["besked"]);
    $PhoneNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["PhoneNumber"]);


    $sql="INSERT INTO outbox (DestinationNumber, Class, TextDecoded)
    VALUES ('$PhoneNumber', '1', '$besked')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php">
```

I hope this makes sense.

I have tried the following

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name']);
$Players = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Players']);
$Game = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Game']);

$besked = "Du har oprettet et spil med navn $Name og er et $Game som mangler $Players spiller(e).";
echo $besked;
echo "<br>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM brugere where $Game = 'Ja'");

$phone_numbers = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $phone_numbers[] =  $row['Phonenumber'];  
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="smssend.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="besked" value="<?php echo "$besked"; ?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="PhoneNumber" value="<?php echo serialize($phone_numbers); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Send data">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the next PHP file

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASSWORD","SMSDATABASE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security

$besked = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["besked"]);
$Phone = unserialize($_POST["PhoneNumber"]);
var_dump($Phone);

/*$sql="INSERT INTO outbox (DestinationNumber, Class, TextDecoded)
VALUES ('$PhoneNumber', '1', '$besked')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Beskeden er sendt";

mysqli_close($con);
*/
?>
```

Please notice that i have canceled the insert into the database in this part.

But when i try to run the file i get the following

bool(false)

Comment: You want to insert database from table to another, or you want to insert it through form??

Comment: I have one table where the users phonenumber and their gaming preferences (Boardgame, Cardgame or Roleplay games) And when you enter what game you need to find players to it takes that info from the first Database and put it in the second database.

Comment: Sorry Arif. Could you please write the IF statement. My knowledge about IF statements are VERY limited.

Comment: Are both databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes Gervs. Both databases are on the same server. The User database is a database i have created but because i use GAMMU or WAMMU to send SMS messages and Gammu have created its own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['Navn'] . " " . $row['VCNummer'];
      echo "<br>";
      $PhoneNumber = $row['Phonenumber']; 
}
```

try this

```
$phone_numbers = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $phone_numbers[] =  $row['Phonenumber'];  
}
```

then try a

```
var_dump($phone_numbers);
```

Comment: A whole new world opens up right in front of my eyes.

But how can i transfer the array between one page and the other plus it now write [0]=> string(8) "12345678"

Comment: You can pass an array inside a hidden value. Just need to serialize it. Tell me if you find any difficulties.

Comment: change this

`<input type="hidden" name="PhoneNumber" value="<?php echo "$PhoneNumber"; ?>">`

into 

`<input type="hidden" name="PhoneNumber" value="<?php echo serialize($phone_numbers); ?>">`

and then in the other script 

use `unserialize($_POST['PhoneNumber'])`

Comment: That did not work.
On the second page where i need to insert into the second database i get this when i try to var_dump
        $Phone = unserialize($_POST["PhoneNumber"]);
        var_dump($Phone);

        bool(false)

Comment: just copy and paste your code line <input type="hidden" name="PhoneNumber" ...... i mean after you changed as i said

Comment: Can you just view source and check the hidden field "PhoneNumber"'s value and let me know. Please reply here.

Comment: problem is serialized data is breaking the html. this will work. `<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($phone_numbers));?>`